# How to toggle a row down to series of square boxes?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, toggle, gridster

I have a grid boxes (Fixed Square Boxes) in a row. When clicking on each box a full row should toggle down. My current code toggles but it pulls all other square boxes down. But what i want is when clicking on square box series of square box should remain same, down to that a new row should toggle down. I have attached fiddle of my code and an image of what i want.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".square").click(function () 
{
$('.slideTogglebox').slideToggle();
});
});
```

```css
.container
{
width:95%;
margin:0 auto;
}

.square
 {
    float:left;
    min-width:250px;
 height:200px;
    margin:1.66%;
    background-color: #1E1E1E;
}
.content{
    color:#fff;
    padding:10px; 
}
 .slideTogglebox{
  float:left;
  padding:8px;
  margin:16px;
  border:1px solid red;
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:#000000;
  color:white;
 }
 .clear{
  clear:both;
 }
 .full
 {
 width:89%;
 
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="full_box">
<div class="square">
<div class="content">
hello
</div>
</div>
<div class="slideTogglebox full">
   slideToggle()
 </div> 
</div>
<div  class="square">
<div class="content">
hello
</div>
</div>
<div  class="square">
<div class="content">
hello
kk
</div>
</div>
<!-- 2nd row */ -->
<div  class="square">
<div class="content">
hello
</div>
</div>
<div  class="square">
<div class="content">
hello
</div>
</div>
<div  class="square">
<div class="content">
hello
</div>
</div>

<!-- 3rd row */ -->
</div>
```

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B69sW.jpg)[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTXvS.jpg)

Comment: this line should work: `$(this).find('.slideTogglebox'). slideToggle();`

Comment: Thanks @ciuak that will toggle respective row down but it should not push down the other right side boxes. Let me know if you can spend couple of minutes by checking attached images i.e down to snippet.

Comment: Did anyone manage to get this working?